# Regex to replace slash and numbers with hyphen from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove numbers and slashes from url. First I am trying to remove slash after number and then again replacing remaining slashes with hyphen.

1. `orders/detail/544` to `orders-detail`
2. `orders/detail/544/edit` to `orders-detail-edit`
3. `users/edit/2` to `users-edit`

I have tried with the regex below which is working for second senerio but not for the first one

`const className = routeUrl.replace(/([0-9]+)\//, '').replace(/[/]/g, '-');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following double replacement seems to be working:

```js
var inputs = ["orders/detail/544", "orders/detail/544/edit", "users/edit/2"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    output = inputs[i].replace(/\/\d+/g, "").replace(/\//g, "-");
    console.log(inputs[i] + " => " + output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid adding arbitrary restrictions to what you need to do, and just handle the code in a clearer manner that won't require comments to explain.

```js
const className = routeUrl.split("/").filter((val) => /\D/.test(val)).join("-");

// or on multiple lines

const className = routeUrl.split("/")
  .filter((val) => /\D/.test(val))
  .join("-");
```

```js
const tests = ["orders/detail/544", "orders/detail/544/edit", "users/edit/2"];

console.log(tests.map((routeUrl) => routeUrl.split("/").filter((val) => /\D/.test(val)).join("-")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` at `/` -> `filter` all the non-numbers using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) ->  `join` with `-`

```js
const transform = str => str.split("/").filter(isNaN).join("-"),
      inputs = ["orders/detail/544", "orders/detail/544/edit", "users/edit/2"],
      outputs = inputs.map(transform)
      
console.log(
  outputs
)
```